# Logarithm of Matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

Can we say  $\log(e^X e^Y)=X+Y \tag 1$ ?

where $X$,$Y$ are general skew symmetric matrices of order $3 \times 3$ (Just mentioned skew symmetric matrices to indicate that these are rotational matrices)

Comment: Unless $X,Y$ happen to commute, there is little hope that this would be true.

Comment: if not commutative what we will do ?

Comment: If not commutative, it is still simple to compute $X+Y$.  However the left hand side, if you happen to need that, will be more difficult to compute.  What is the fundamental goal you want to accomplish?

Comment: Please Wait I will write an answer below with my view in 10 min..

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to post, but unless it happens to be an Answer to the Question above, the new material might be better used as an Edit to the Question, giving some context to what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can't even say that $\log(e^X)=X$, since the matrix exponential is not an injective function. What you mean to ask should be formulated differently.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT 1. Remark 1. For general complex (or real ) matrices $e^Xe^Y=e^{X+Y}$ does not imply $XY=YX$. For example, let $A=60i\pi\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},B=\pi\begin{pmatrix}-150i&-91\\391&150i\end{pmatrix}$. Then $e^{tA+B}=e^{tA}e^B$ for $t=1,2,3,4,5$ and $e^{t(A+B)}=e^{tA}e^{tB}$ for every positive integer ; yet $AB\not=BA$.

Remark 2. Let $\log$ be the principal logarithm ; it is a matrix function (cf. Higham, matrix functions). Even if we assume that the eigenvalues of $X,Y$ have imaginary parts in $(-\pi,\pi)$ and $XY=YX$, the formula $\log(e^Xe^Y)=X+Y$ is false. Choose, for instance, these skew symmetric matrices:
$X=Y=\begin{pmatrix}0&2\pi/3\\-2\pi/3&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Remark 3. One might wonder if the implication in Remark 1 would be true for real skew symmetric matrices $X,Y$. In dimension $2$, it is clear because $2$ skew symmetric matrices commute. In dimension $3$, it  is not, in particular because the couples $(X,Y)$ in $M_3(\mathbb{C})$ or $M_3(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $e^Xe^Y=e^{X+Y}$ are unknown. To a skew symmetric matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-a_3&a_2\\a_3&0&-a_1\\-a_2&a_1&0\end{pmatrix}$, we associate the vector $a=[a_1,a_2,a_3]^T$ and $e^A$ is the rotation $Rot(a,||a||)$. Then the question is: does the relation $Rot(a,||a||)\circ Rot(b,||b||)=Rot(a+b,||a+b||)$ imply that $AB=BA$, that is, $a,b$ are parallel vectors ? I do not know the answer.

EDIT 2. The above assertion (in Remark 3.) is almost true. We identify a vector with a point.

Case 1. Assume that $||a||$ is not in $2\pi\mathbb{N}^*$. Let $c=Rot(a,||a||)(b)=Rot(a+b,||a+b||)(b)$. Then $c\in\Gamma_1$, the circle, with axis $a$, that goes through $b$ ; moreover $c\in\Gamma_2$, the circle, with axis $a+b$, that goes through $b$. Both circles have same tangent in $b$. Then $c=b$ (that is impossible) except if $\Gamma_1=\Gamma_2$. Finally $a,a+b$ are parallel vectors and we are done.

Case 2. If $||a||$ and $||b||$ are in $2\pi\mathbb{N}^*$, then there are counter-examples as the following one: $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-6\pi\\0&6\pi&0\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&8\pi\\0&0&0\\-8\pi&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

EDIT 3. Answer to Nick. Your wikipedia reference gives a false BCH formula! Indeed, if $\log$ is the principal logarithm, then it is false even over $\mathbb{C}$: take $X=Y=2i\pi/3$ as in my Remark 2. The correct formula is (for example) here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group  $e^ue^v=e^{u+v+\cdots}$. Thus $XY=YX$ does not imply that $\log(e^Xe^Y)=X+Y$.

The converse is also false (even in dimension $2$ over $\mathbb{C}$): assume that $\log(e^Xe^Y)=X+Y$, that is equivalent to $e^Xe^Y=e^{X+Y},spectrum(X+Y)\subset \mathbb{R}\times (-i\pi,i\pi]$. A counter-example is given by $X=\begin{pmatrix}u&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},Y=\begin{pmatrix}-u&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, where $e^u=1+u,u\not= 0$ (for example $u\approx 2.0888+7.4615i$).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $\left\|e^{X}e^{Y}-I\right\| < 1$ (which assures convergence of the series defining the matrix logarithm) and that $\left\|X\right\|$ and $\left\|Y\right\|$ are small, then the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) says
\begin{align}
\log(\exp(X)\exp(Y)) = X + Y + \frac{1}{2}[X,Y] + \frac{1}{12}\left([X,[X,Y]] +[Y,[Y,X]] \right) + \cdots
\end{align}
and hence $\log(\exp(X)\exp(Y)) = X + Y$ iff $[X,Y] = 0$. From the previous answer we have seen that skew-symmetry does not imply commutativity, so in general we cannot say $\log(\exp(X)\exp(Y)) = X + Y$ for skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: @ Nick Thompson , your equivalence is false. See my EDIT 3 above.

Comment: The assumption that $\|X\|$ and $\|Y\|$ are small defines a domain on which $\exp$ is injective. Admittedly, this is not part of the question as stated, but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Comment: @ Nick Thompson , of course if you assume that $X,Y$ are small, then $XY=YX$ implies $\log(e^Xe^Y)=X+Y$. Consider the converse, that is: let $X,Y$ be small s.t. $e^Xe^Y=e^{X+Y}$ ; is $XY=YX$ true ? If $n=2$, then the answer is YES (it is not obvious) ; yet, if $n>2$, then I do not know the answer in the general case - it is true if $[X,Y]$ commute with $X$ and $Y$.-